# Pullback and pushforward

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Say I have a scheme $X$, irreducible and of finite type over a field $k$, and a closed subscheme $Y$ of $X$ with associated closed immersion $i: Y \to X$. Consider a sheaf $F$ on $X$ (for the étale topology).

How should I think about the sheaf $i_* i^* F$ and the kernel of $F \to i_* i^* F$ in a more or less "concrete" way? Is it possible to visualize these sheaves somehow, or at least to compare them with $F$ in an imaginative way?